# Can I have more than 320px content in an iPhone, using viewport tag with device-width and initial-scale = 1?

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile, viewport

I'm developing a website that I want to feel "appy", for users that'll access it through phones, tablets, and desktop PCs. I'm using jQuery Mobile for that.

For some reason, jQuery mobile *requires* a viewport tag with "width=device-width, initial-scale=1".

If I choose any other width, any other initial-scale, or I remove either, then jQuery mobile behaves horribly bad. (transitions look jerky, things jump up and down, it's horrible).

Now, 320px is a bit narrow for my content, and I was kind of counting on setting the width of the viewport to at least 480px, maybe more, so that things would just look "smaller", and there'd still be no horizontal scrolling.

Is there any other way to achieve this (basically, being able to fit more than 320px of content), while still keeping the viewport tag as jquery mobile requires it?

Thanks!
Daniel