# What happens if layout viewport is smaller than visual viewport?

Tags: css, iphone, viewport

An explanation of **layout viewport** and **visual viewport** can be found [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html).

I have read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) and [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries3.shtml) that one should use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
```

if one wants to optimize a webpage for mobile devices.

I would like to understand the consequences of this on the iphone4 in landscape mode. I would think that the following happens:

**width=device-width**
The device width of the iphone4 is 320px in landscape (see [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml)) even though the iphone 4 has a screen-width of 480px in landscape mode. So the layout viewport is set to 320px.

**initial-scale=1.0** This sets 1 CSS pixel to 1 device pixel (see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)). Now since the iphone4 has a width of 480 device pixel, this implies for me that the visual viewport is 480px wide.

Thus, the layout viewport is set to 320px and the visual viewport to 480px. Doesn't that imply that the webpage is only shown on the first 320 px of the visual viewport and the remaing 160px are left blank?

To give a more concrete example: Consider the following webpage

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html >
  <head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='background-color:red;width:100%'>Test</div>     
  </body>
</html>
```

then in my understanding, this should only fill the screen of the iphone4 in landscape to 320/480=66,66% with red, because the layout viewport would get the length of 320px and since the div-size is relative to the viewport, *width:100%* is the same as *width:320 px*, see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html):

> the CSS layout, especially percentual widths, are calculated relative
>   to the layout viewport

I am assuming that I am wrong and that the iphone4 will probably display the above page in landscape with 100% red - but why? Have I misunderstood something?

Remark: I found this question [Can I have more than 320px content in an iPhone, using viewport tag with device-width and initial-scale = 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17063990/can-i-have-more-than-320px-content-in-an-iphone-using-viewport-tag-with-device?rq=1) which is closly related to my question but with no answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mozilla's documentation of the viewport meta tag explains this behavior fairly well (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

> For pages that set an initial or maximum scale, this means the width property actually translates into a minimum viewport width. For example, if your layout needs at least 500 pixels of width then you can use the following markup. When the screen is more than 500 pixels wide, the browser will expand the viewport (rather than zoom in) to fit the screen:
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=500, initial-scale=1">
> ```

By extension, if `width=device-width` resolves to 320 but the screen is 480 pixels wide, the browser will also expand the layout viewport to 480.

Also from the same document:

> Mobile Safari often just zooms the page when changing from portrait to landscape, instead of laying out the page as it would if originally loaded in landscape.

I think that behavior has changed somewhat in recent versions of iOS, but it can be a confounding factor in figuring out what is going on, as on some devices the layout viewport will sometimes be different when a page is loaded in landscape vs. when the page is loaded in portrait and then rotated to landscape.

Mozilla goes on to say:

> If web developers want their scale settings to remain consistent when switching orientations on the iPhone, they must add a maximum-scale value to prevent this zooming, which has the sometimes-unwanted side effect of preventing users from zooming in:
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
> ```

I'm not a fan of this technique; I think the cure is worse than the disease in most cases.

Comment: Oh wow! I was reading the same article (its the first reference of my OP) but I must have missed it.. Thank you so much for pointing it out to me.

Comment: But why do people then recommend **<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">** and not simply **<meta name="viewport" content="width=initial-scale=1.0">**? Is there a difference?

Comment: I haven't tested extensively, but I think the behavior without width=device-width varies depending on browser and version, especially after rotation. Also behavior would be quite different for designs where width of some elements exceeds device width. While this isn't good practice, it's easy to do accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is rotating page rendered in portrait mode. You will have to redraw page. Here is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043956/refreshing-page-automatically-when-viewport-size-change) .

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Of course the page will be rendered again when I switch in landscape mode, but even in landscape-mode the device-width is 320px instead of 480px. I don't see similarities to your linked questions. Still thank you for your answer.

Comment: This is weird. As I've seen this problem. After rotation from portrait you still had same pixels width. And looks like it didn't scale width to fit screen size. So what I'm saying is that you might want to try to manually redraw page after rotation using javascript. I also don't have iPhone 4 but I checked your code on iPad 1 and it's working just fine.

Comment: I am not saying that I have experienced the problem. I am just saying that according to the definition of the layout viewport I would expect that behavior but on the same times it seems weird to me, so I asked if my argumentation has  a missing link or something. I just edited my question, hope its more clear now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you have is confusing the device-width and screen/browser resolution.

as in the [example](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) you post:

> These pixels have nothing to do with the actual pixel density of the device, or even with the rumoured upcoming intermediate layer. They’re essentially an abstract construct created specifically for us web developers.

---

> In other words, width/height mirrors the values of document. documentElement. clientWidth/Height, while device-width/height mirrors the values of screen.width/height. (They actually do so in all browsers, even if the mirrored values are incorrect.)

they are retina display and the difference is only in bigger pixel rendering from the iphone, so the browser will rendere full-screen even with 320px device-width in landscape. the big problem with iphone is that this difference don't change between portrait/landscape.

and

> You can set the layout viewport’s width to any dimension you want, including device-width. That last one takes screen.width (in device pixels) as its reference and resizes the layout viewport accordingly.

where the device pixel (`The screen`) is different from `visual viewport`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0" />
```

there device-width will have always 100% screen width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px;initial-scale=1.0" />
```

there you should test if there are no changes on iphone or the DIV will extend out/gap of the screen in landscape

---

i think this source is correct only using media-query with device-width (not visible on iphone), because if you use normal media query you can see that the effective pixel-ratio of the browser rendering changes from 320px to 480px

> max-width is the width of the target display area, e.g. the browser; max-device-width is the width of the device's entire rendering area, i.e. the actual device screen.
>
> - If you are using the max-device-width, when you change the size of the browser window on your desktop, the CSS style won't change to different media query setting;
> - If you are using the max-width, when you change the size of the browser on your desktop, the CSS will change to different media query setting and you might be shown with the styling for mobiles, such as touch-friendly menus.

Comment: I dont think that I confuse them: The screen resolution of the Iphone4 is 320x480px with device-pixel-ratio:2, and the device-resolution (which is independet of the device-pixel-ratio) is 640x960px. Further, the device-width is 320px in landscape for the iPhone4 (because it always returns the screen-width of portrait mode). My problem remains: If I set the layout-viewport to 320 px, and the visual viewport to 480, then I dont understand why this doesnt result ina 160px gap.

Comment: because as i wrote in the last note the browser resolution change based on the width of the device that will be rendered at 480px but is not linked to device-width.
try to set the width of the div at 320px instead of 100%, you will see that the gap will appear in landscape mode.
you don't have any media-query to reproduce the gap, you should need to set a media query like this: `@media screen and(max-device-width:320px)` and test it on any no-iphone device, or `@media screen and(max-width:320px)` if you want test it on iphone because the device-width don't change.